# O número de compilação de incremento automático não funciona

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Tenho as essas configurações para as informações da versão ao construir meu projeto Delphi 10.3 no Campo Builder 2.1.745.3. Mesmo se o "Número de compilação de incremento automático" estiver marcado, o número nunca aumenta. Como configurar isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só para garantir, vc está compilando (Ctrl+F9) ou "buildando" (Shift+F9) o projeto?

Comment: Ctrl+F9 e as vezes F9

Comment: Para funcionar o auto incremento do build, é necessário dar o "Build", no caso "Shift+F9".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para funcionar o auto incremento do build, é necessário dar o **build** no projeto.
Há diferença entre compilar e buildar o projeto.

- Compilar: Ctrl+F9
- Buildar: Shift+F9